# Django 1.6 301 url redirect not working

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm trying to do a a 301 redirect using the django redirect app but I still keep getting the 404 page when I visit the old url. I followed the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/redirects/ and added a old and new url in database but it's still not working.

Is there any other way of doing a 301 redirection

I have this url `http://localhost:8000/doclistings/?speciality=Dentist` and I want it to be redirected to `http://localhost:8000/doclistings/?speciality=Dentists`

urls.py

```
url(r'^doclistings/$', views.doclistings, name='doclistings'),
```

views.py

```
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.GET)
        try:
            s_name = request.GET['speciality']
        except:
            s_name = None
        try:
            l_name = request.GET['language']
        except:
            l_name = None
        try:
            g_name = request.GET['gender']
        except:
            g_name = None

        d['s_name'] = s_name # adding these to the forms for the "selected" option
        d['l_name'] = l_name
        d['g_name'] = g_name


        try:
            doctors = filter_doctors(request=request, specialization=s_name, gender=g_name, language=l_name).order_by('-netlikes')

        except Exception:
            return error404(request)

    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()

    d['doctors'] = doctors
    d.update({'form': form, 'languages': Language.objects.all()})
    return render_to_response('m1/doclistings.html',d)
```

Comment: Hi have you considered just point both url to the same view in urls.py

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I've updated the question with views and urls

Comment: Are you sure your `doctors = ...` in the try except expression is correct? It seems your 404 error come from here....

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to do redirect. Correct me if I'm wrong but you want to access the value of the speciality and if the user key in `Dentist` you want it to be `Dentists`.

I think the correct way to ensure the key, value of a GET request get filled in properly is by form validation. There are many ways of doing form validation, you can do it with javascript or by django form.

However, a quick hack around your problem to pass in some logic into your code, that if the value of `speciality` == `'doctor'`, you set it to `doctors` instead

For instance,

```
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.GET)
        try:
            s_name = request.GET['speciality']
            if s_name == 'Dentist':
                s_name = 'Dentists'
        except:
            s_name = None
        try:
            l_name = request.GET['language']
        except:
            l_name = None
        try:
            g_name = request.GET['gender']
        except:
            g_name = None

        d['s_name'] = s_name # adding these to the forms for the "selected" option
        d['l_name'] = l_name
        d['g_name'] = g_name


        try:
            doctors = filter_doctors(request=request, specialization=s_name, gender=g_name, language=l_name).order_by('-netlikes')

        except Exception:
            return error404(request)

    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()

    d['doctors'] = doctors
    d.update({'form': form, 'languages': Language.objects.all()})
    return render_to_response('m1/doclistings.html',d)
```

Let me know if this works for you

Cheers,
BioBirdMan